# Get data from JSON API in my MainActivity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java, mvp, android-lifecycle

My project use MVP architecture and RxJava to get data from a remote JSON Api.

I have a MainActivity, it has 2 roles. The first one is to be a fragment container, the  second one is to get data from the JSON api and transmit it to my fragment (I only have one fragment for now but will have another one later using the same data).

For now, I'm getting the data in my MainActivity. I'm trying to get the data from my fragment by calling a method in my MainActivity (using an interface for decoupling).

The problem is the data in my fragment is always empty, I suppose it's because my activity inflate my fragment so fast that when my fragment calls my activity method to get the data this data is still empty since the request didn't receive the answer yet and this request is called asynchronously using RxJava.

So I want to wait for the data being loaded to open my fragment,or open my fragment and wait the data being loaded in the activity before get it (showing a visual progress to the user). The problem is not really how to do this but when and where. Thank you for your help.

I moved my loadData() method and the transaction to open my fragment several times in different positions in the lifecycle, nothing worked. For now everything is in in MainActivity.onStart() :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    presenter.setView(this);

    // Load data from JSON API
    presenter.loadData(city, authToken);

    // Load fragments
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.ll_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new PollutionLevelsFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.ll_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

The data is retrieve in the loadData() method of my presenter :

```
   public class MainPresenter implements MainActivityMVP.Presenter {
    final static String TAG = MainPresenter.class.getCanonicalName();
    private MainActivityMVP.View view;
    private MainActivityMVP.Model model;
    private Subscription subscription = null;


    public MainPresenter(MainActivityMVP.Model model) { this.model = model; }

    @Override

    public void loadData(String city, String authToken) {

        subscription = model.result(city, authToken)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Aqicn>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i(TAG,"completed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Aqicn aqicn) {

                        Data data = aqicn.getData();
                        Iaqi iaqi = data.getIaqi();

                        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(data.getAqi(),
                                data.getDominentpol(),
                                iaqi.getCo().getV(),
                                iaqi.getH().getV(),
                                iaqi.getNo2().getV(),
                                iaqi.getO3().getV(),
                                iaqi.getP().getV(),
                                iaqi.getPm10().getV(),
                                iaqi.getPm25().getV(),
                                iaqi.getR().getV(),
                                iaqi.getSo2().getV(),
                                iaqi.getT().getV(),
                                iaqi.getW().getV());

                        Log.d(TAG,data.getCity().getName());
                        if (view != null) {
                            view.updateData(viewModel);
                        }
                }

            });


    }
    @Override

    public void rxUnsubscribe() {
        if (subscription != null) {
            if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override

    public void setView(MainActivityMVP.View view) {
            this.view = view;
    }

}
```

When the response to the request is received the presenter call the updateData() method in MainActivity (see in my presenter code above). This is where I initialize the ArrayList pollutionLevels that is supposed to contain the data I try to get from my fragment :

```
@Override
public void updateData(ViewModel viewModel) {
    this.pollutionData = viewModel;

    pollutionLevels = viewModel.getAllPolluants();

    for(PollutionLevel p : pollutionLevels) {
        Log.d(TAG,p.getName());
    }

}
```

This is the method in my MainActivity called from my fragment to get data :

```
@Override
public ArrayList<PollutionLevel> getPollutionLevels() {
    return pollutionLevels;
}
```

In my fragment I try to get the data in onAttach() but it's always empty :

```
public interface PollutionLevelsListener{
    ArrayList<PollutionLevel> getPollutionLevels();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        pollutionLevelsListener = (PollutionLevelsListener) context;
        ArrayList<PollutionLevel> levels = pollutionLevelsListener.getPollutionLevels();

        for(PollutionLevel l:levels) {
            Log.d(TAG,l.getName());
        }

    } catch (ClassCastException castException){
        castException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT : add ViewModel.getAllPolluants() method**

This is the method in my ViewModel that returns the ArrayList :

```
public ArrayList<PollutionLevel> getAllPolluants() {
    ArrayList<PollutionLevel> allLevels = new ArrayList();
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("Co",Double.toString(co)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("H",Double.toString(h)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("No2",Double.toString(no2)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("o3",Double.toString(o3)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("p",Double.toString(p)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("o3",Double.toString(o3)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("pm10",Integer.toString(pm10)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("pm25",Integer.toString(pm25)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("r",Double.toString(r)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("so2",Double.toString(so2)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("t",Double.toString(t)));
    allLevels.add(new PollutionLevel("w",Double.toString(w)));

    return allLevels;
}
```

**EDIT : Add new modified MainActivity class and PollutionLevelListener interface, trying to apply @cricket_007 answer**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityMVP.View, PollutionLevelsListener {
    final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();

    @BindString(R.string.city)
    String city;

    @BindString(R.string.aqicn_token)
    String authToken;

    @Inject
    MainActivityMVP.Presenter presenter;

    ArrayList<PollutionLevel> pollutionLevels;

    PollutionLevelsListener pollutionListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        ((App) getApplication()).getComponent().injectPollutionLevels(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateData(ViewModel viewModel) {
        pollutionLevels = viewModel.getAllPolluants();

        for(PollutionLevel p : pollutionLevels) {
            Log.d(TAG,p.getName());
        }

        //===== NullPointerException
        pollutionListener.onPollutionLevelsLoaded(pollutionLevels);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        presenter.setView(this);
        presenter.loadData(city, authToken);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPollutionLevelsLoaded(List<PollutionLevel> levels) {
        for(PollutionLevel p : pollutionLevels) {
            Log.d(TAG,p.getName());
        };

        // Load fragments
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.ll_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new PollutionLevelsFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.ll_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        presenter.rxUnsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface PollutionLevelsListener {
    void onPollutionLevelsLoaded(List<PollutionLevel> levels);
}
```

**#################### EDIT ########################**

After a lot of doubt with what solution to adopt I follow the answer and recommendations of @yosriz. This is the code I ended with. Be aware that I still need to implement a cache management feature as for now the JSON resquest is made for both fragment.

As a result I have a common repository used by my both fragment. The MainActivity became only a fragment container, it doesn't get any data. it doesn't even have a MVP structure since I think It's now useless.

**My both fragment (so my both features) get their data from `PollutionLevelRepository`** :

```
public interface Repository {
    Observable<Aqicn> getPollutionLevelsFromNetwork(String city, String authToken);
    Observable<Aqicn> getPollutionLevels(String city, String authToken);
}


public class PollutionLevelsRepository implements Repository {
    private PollutionApiService pollutionApiService;
    private static Observable<Aqicn> pollutionData = null;


    public PollutionLevelsRepository(PollutionApiService pollutionApiService) {
        this.pollutionApiService = pollutionApiService;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getPollutionLevelsFromNetwork(String city, String authToken) {
        pollutionData = pollutionApiService.getPollutionObservable(city, authToken);
        return pollutionData;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getPollutionLevels(String city, String authToken) {
        return getPollutionLevelsFromNetwork(city, authToken);
    }
}
```

The Model of my first fragment (Donut feature) :

```
public class DonutModel implements DonutFragmentMVP.Model {
    final static String TAG = DonutModel.class.getSimpleName();
    private Repository repository;

    public DonutModel(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getPollutionLevels(String city, String authToken) {

        Observable<Aqicn> aqicnObservable = repository.getPollutionLevels(city, authToken);
        return aqicnObservable;
    }
}
```

The Model of my second fragment (Pollution level feature) :

```
public class PollutionLevelsModel implements PollutionLevelsFragmentMVP.Model {

    private Repository repository;

    public PollutionLevelsModel(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> result(String city, String authToken) {

        Observable<Aqicn> aqicnObservable = repository.getPollutionLevels(city, authToken);
        return aqicnObservable;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to add to a list? But `onNext` only generates one `ViewModel`?

Comment: in the updateData() method of my MainActivity there is a call to the method getAllPolluants() in my ViewModel. This call return an Arraylist : `pollutionLevels = viewModel.getAllPolluants();`I gonna edit my question, maybe it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you probably have timing issue, the `model.result` is async IO operation that will update data on activity in async fashion when it will finish, while your fragment call to get the data is happening as soon as the fragment attached the activity (which is still async as you call fragment `commit()` and not `commitNow()`) but if you compare it to the probably network call of `model.result` it will be probably always faster.

Actually I think your approach is wrong, when you're using reactive fashion with Rx you should push the data, here at the end, you're pulling it at the fragment side from the `Activity`, while you don't know if this data is already available.
The data that is loaded from the presenter should update immediately the fragment, meaning either your `Activity.updateData()` will update the fragment, or more correct approach to my opinion is that the presenter will be tied to the fragment itself as this is the actual `View` it's updating, so the `view.UpdateData()` at the presenter will notify the fragment directly.

Comment: I see your logic and agree with it. But About your suggestion "the presenter will be tied to the fragment itself". The thing is I planned to have another fragment using the same data (one fragment as a chart and the other showing the same data as text). If i understand good you mean retrieving my data in the presenter of my fragment, but since i'll have two fragments with the same data it means i'll do two JSON requests in both presenters of my both fragments. It's what i did before and it worked but it's two times the same requests it's why I'm trying to move everything to the MainActivity.

Comment: well, it is not crucial to the problem, as it's just a symptom, my point is that I think, that presenter should drive the view and not the opposite, so if you have 2 fragments (I guess that's means 2 screens), if you have some data that it shares between them, you can save it somewhere and the presenter will deliver the same data to both screens.

Comment: anyhow, the more crucial point is that when the presenter updates the view, then the UI will be updated directly, so even if your activity is the view interface for the presenter, that switches the fragments, it should update directly the fragment (UI), as in this case the activity drives the fragments. otherwise how the fragment will know about changes, while the presenter doesn't 'know' the fragment and just updates the activity?

Comment: ok, so you suggest I should have a common Repository for my both fragments ?. My two fragments will not be necessarily two different screens, it will depends on the device screen size. So If I have these both fragment on the same screen that uses a common Repository it means I must deal with kind of two methods like loadDataFromNetwork() and loadDataFromMemory() to avoid double requests.

Comment: I suggest that view will be dumb (passive view approach in MVP), so indeed the presenter and not the activity should save the data for reuse when different view (fragment) is used. That is means you need to store the data in presenter side and when trying to load the data again, bring it from cache, you can use repository or whatever suits you, and yes, then you should handle simple in memory cache to avoid repeating queries

Comment: Ok, I see your point. In MVP the view as to be passive. As I use it directly to transfer data between views the views are not passive anymore. It looks like this "passive" notion can have several interpretation because I read a lot in SO about data passing data directly between views in MVP. Anyway I must admit I have some doubt about what the best approach now.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to get the data from my fragment by calling a method in my MainActivity

It seems your interface is only returning the field, which could very possibly be before the request has finished. Which you seem to understand...

> didn't receive the answer yet and this request is called asynchronously using RxJava

I wouldn't suggest you wait, and instead do

> open my fragment and wait the data being loaded in the activity before get it (showing a visual progress to the user).

However you want to implement that, you can try a `new ProgressDialog()` and show / hide that.

---

Your issue is that `onAttach` gets immediately called and the request is still going on indefinitely.

You need to "subscribe" for that data from the Fragment.

A "listener" is not typically written to implement a "getter", so let's rewrite that

```
public interface PollutionLevelsListener {
    void onPollutionLevelsLoaded(List<PollutionLevel> levels);
}
```

Then, you can use that instead to start your Fragment rather than immediately when the Activity starts

```
// The Activity

class ... implements PollutionLevelsListener {

    @Override
    public void onPollutionLevelsLoaded(List<PollutionLevel> levels) {
        for(PollutionLevel p : pollutionLevels) {
            Log.d(TAG,p.getName());
        };

        // Moved this section here

        // Load fragments
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.ll_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new PollutionLevelsFragment();

            // If your object is Parcelable
            /* 
            * Bundle args = new Bundle();
            * args.putParcelableArrayList(levels);
            * fragment.setArguments(args);
            */

            ft.add(R.id.ll_container, fragment).commit();
        }

    }
```

And now that you have that method,

> the presenter call the updateData() method **in MainActivity**

Well, there's where the list comes from, so just pass it to that new method where the Fragment is then loaded

```
@Override
public void updateData(ViewModel viewModel) {
    this.pollutionData = viewModel;

    if (pollutionLevels == null) {
        pollutionsLevels = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    pollutionLevels.clear();
    pollutionLevels.addAll(viewModel.getAllPolluants());

    this.onPollutionLevelsLoaded(pollutionsLevels);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like a good approach to me so I'm sorry I can't get it works, there are some points I can't understand. My MainActivity has to implement the `PollutionLevelsListener` Interface... So I have this `onPollutionLevelsLoaded()` method in MainActivity. When the data is updated from my Presenter it calls MainActivity.updateData(ViewModel) in my MainActivity. For what I understand updateData is only called by my Presenter once  the data is loaded.

Comment: So the fragment is only inflated once I get the data since the fragment is loaded in the method `onPollutionLevelsLoaded()` and this method is called from `updateData()`, of what I understand it's in contradiction with "I wouldn't suggest you wait, and instead do open my fragment and wait the data being loaded in the activity".  Anyway I tried to implement it because I think it's about something I can't get but can't figure out how and where instantiate `levelListener`.

Comment: I can't follow your question that well, but that `View` class should contain a field for that listener interface.

Comment: To be more clear I edited my question and put all my `MainActivity` class code. Yes it is my view that is suppose to get data from the JSON API and pass it to my both fragments. I get a NullPointerException with `pollutionListener.onPollutionLevelsLoaded(pollutionLevels)`  in `updateData()`

Comment: Nullpointerexception on what? I have null catches on both the Arraylist and the listener in my answer

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just implemented your solution but was not able to make it works so tried to modified things, put in different places and didn't realize I got rid of your null checks on the way.... and didn't check back your solution again at the end. Anyway I think I use to much of your patience, i'll try to achieve this on my own using your solution because I think it's the good one. Once done i'll accept your answer and i'll put the details here to help people who (like me) need more time or more details to understand. Thank you for your time again.

Comment: I tried several times to figure out the best place to implement the listener. The way it is currently in the answer, you would have the equivalent of `mvpView.setLevelListener(MVPActivity.this)`, where you have implemented the interface on the Activity, as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Wait... If `updateData` is in the Activity you don't even need my interface! Replace `pollutionListener.onPollutionLevelsLoaded(pollutionLevels);` with simply `this.onPollutionLevelsLoaded(pollutionLevels);`... You have that method right there!

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to make an method inside the fragment and you can hit it once updateData(ViewModel viewModel) called ?

for example (try to add this method in you fragment):

```
public class YourFragmentName extends Fragment {

    public YourFragmentName(StepsHandler stepsHandler){
        this.stepsHandler = stepsHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_supplier_registrtion_first, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }
    public void dataLoaded() {
        // Do what you need after data finish loading.. 
    }
}
```

From your Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements StepsHandler {

    YourFragmentName fragmentName;

    //onCreate ()
            fragmentName = new YourFragmentName(this);

    @Override
    public void updateData(ViewModel viewModel) {
        this.pollutionData = viewModel;

        pollutionLevels = viewModel.getAllPolluants();
        fragmentName.dataLoaded();
        for(PollutionLevel p : pollutionLevels) {
            Log.d(TAG,p.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like an easy way to achieve this. I would just have to use an Interface for decoupling instead of calling the Fragment method directly.